# Customized Iterator for the Process.repeatEval in scalaz stream

Tags: scala, scalaz

I want to parse infinite urls by using scalaz stream. The template url response looks like this :

```
{
 nextUrl: "nextUrl"
}
```

I am thinking to use scalaz Stream to parse infinitely. The method I am gonna to use is Process.repeatEval. However, it is little bit hard to do it since the next link is embedded inside the current url. Thus, I create a customized iterator and here is some pseudo code

```
class Iterator {
  var currentUrl = null //state...

  def hasNext(): Boolean

  def next(): UrlContent

}

Process.repeatEval(Task {iterator}).takeWhile(_.hasNext()).map(_.next()).run.run
```

It is working, but I am not a fun of this, because iterator has state, and I am trying to remove the usage of mutable value.

Back to my question, am I looking for the suitable choice (Process.repeatEval) from scalaz stream. If yes, should I use this customized iterator.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: By `scalaz stream` do you mean [FS2](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2) or [`scalaz.StreamT`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.0/scalaz_2.11-7.2.0-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.package) ?

Comment: sry for the late reply, I am using this ``` org.scalaz.stream" %% "scalaz-stream" % "0.8 ```